# CouchDB equivalent of Sql NOT IN?

Tags: join, couchdb, contains, notin

I'm looking for the CouchDB JS view equivalent of the following LinQ query :

```
    var query =
        from f in context.Feed
        where !(from ds in context.DataSource
                select ds.Feed_ID)
        .Contains(f.ID)
        select f;
```

Where DataSources have a foreign key to Feeds.

In a word : get all Feeds not associated with a DataSource

Thank you

Comment: You mean 'get all Feeds not associated with a specific Datasource' or 'get all feeds not associated with ANY DataSource'?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [view collation](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation) to join feeds and data sources in map:

```
function(doc) {
  if (!doc.type) return;
  if (doc.type == "feed") emit(doc._id, null);
  if (doc.type == "ds" && doc.feed) emit(doc.feed, null);
}
```

and reduce to filter those feed ids which have data source documents linking to them. Eg. use of the [build-in](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Built-In_Reduce_Functions) `_count` and query with [group_level](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options):

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/test/_design/join/_view/not_in?group_level=1
```

for database:

```
{"id":"1", "type":"feed"}
{"id":"2", "type":"feed"}
{"id":"3", "type":"ds", "feed":1}
{"id":"4", "type":"ds", "feed":1}}
```

will give you:

```
{"rows":[
{"key":"1","value":3},
{"key":"2","value":1}
]}
```

Values `>1` are those feed docs which have reference from data sources. To get pure feed list w/o datasources you can omit records with `value>1` in client or [list function](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Formatting_with_Show_and_List#Listing_Views_with_CouchDB_0.10_and_later).

**Edit:** With list function:

```
function(head, req) {
  var row;
  while (row = getRow()) {
    if (row.value == 1)
      send(row.key + "\n");
  }
}
```

and query:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/test/_design/join/_list/not_ds/not_in?group_level=1
```

You will get the final result with feed documents with out reference from data sources. It is plaint text with list of ids, you can also format it for JSON array.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61844995/how-to-write-a-view-in-couchdb-to-represent-not-in-or-group-by-having-count

Comment: As well as

>>>



List functions are deprecated in CouchDB 3.0, and will be removed in CouchDB 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

The straight answer to *CouchDB equivalent of Sql NOT IN* is: **There is no equivalent.**
There is no querying option in the [couchdb view API](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#View_Generation_Options) for *NOT IN*.

However, there may be alternative ways to achieve your objectives depending if you are interested in getting feeds *associated to no datasource* or *not associated to a specific datasource*.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but having been confronted with the same problem I think that Marcin's answer is correct but incomplete.

In my case I used the following list function to select get all rows except the ones with a certain ***excludeId***:

```
function(head, req) {
start({ 'headers': { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } });
 var rows = [];
 while (row = getRow()) {
    if (!req.query.exceptId || doc.documentId != req.query.exceptId) {
        rows.push(row);
    }
 }
 send(JSON.stringify({ total_rows: rows.length, rows: rows }));
}
```

you can read more [here](http://www.coding-dude.com/wp/web-design/javascript/what-is-couchdb-equivalent-of-sql-not-in-or-not-equals/)