# List Blog Posts without comments in couchDB

Tags: couchdb

I'm writing an application which uses CouchDB for its database. The application has similar qualities to the blog examples often used to illustrate Couchdb. There are "anchor" documents like posts which have other documents which refer to a particular post, like comments on a blog. (Each of the "comments" has a field which is like a sql foreign key. It contains the unique ID of the "post")

However, the "comments" documents are of various types, and one of those types makes the blog post no longer relevant to the application. (The blog "post" is a record of a medical treatment, the "comment" type which I am referring to is a report that indicates that the treatment has finished).

I am stuck trying to work out how to write a view which would emit a list of all the "posts" which do not have one of these treatment-finished documents ( like "comments" ) attached. Can anybody help me with this?

I can not just have an "active" field on the main "post" document, as there are multiple mobile clients which update this document, and I wish to avoid any revision conflicts if two of the clients were to modify the anchor document before coming back into network coverage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation to count the comments in post with map and reduce and filter out the post with more then 0 comments with list function exactly like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413953/couchdb-equivalent-of-sql-not-in/14415896#14415896) to question "CouchDB equivalent of Sql NOT IN?".

View "count_comments":

```
map: function(doc) {
  if (!doc.type) return;
  if (doc.type == "post") emit(doc._id, null);
  if (doc.type == "comment" && doc.post) emit(doc.post, null);
}

reduce: _count
```

List:

```
no_comments: function(head, req) {
  var row;
  while (row = getRow()) {
    if (row.value == 1)
      send(row.key + "\n");
  }
}
```

Query:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/mydb/_design/post_n_comments/_list/no_comments/count_comments?group_level=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have *posts* in one DB and *comments* in another DB, then this problem can't be solved with couchdb as you would be trying to perform a "join" and **there are no joins in couchdb**. In this case you need to work in your server client to query boths DBs separately and show only those posts with allowed comments.

Otherwise, if you have everything in one DB then you would need to embed your comments inside your posts and then writing a view that emits only posts with valid comments would be trivial.