# How to write a view in CouchDB to represent "not in" or "group by having count(*) = 1"?

Tags: sql, nosql, couchdb, pouchdb

Using relational db as an example, given two tables like below, where when rows in `tableA` and `tableB` have the same values, they represent the same "thing" but in different "state". So for ID=1, this thing has gone through stage1 and 2. But for ID=2, this thing has only gone through stage1.

```
tableA (Id, columnA, columnB)
         1, "a", "b"
         2, "x", "y"
         3, "z", "a"
tableB (Id, columnA, columnB)
         1, "e", "f"
```

I want to find all the rows from `tableA` that **don't exist** in `tableB`.

```
select  a.*
from    tableA a
  left join
        tableB b
  on    a.Id = b.Id
where   b.Id is null
```

So above SQL will show rows 2 and 3 from tableA.

How can I do similar things in CouchDB? Say I have 4 docs that look like below.

```
{ "_id":"a-1", "type":"A", "correlation_id": "1" }
{ "_id":"a-2", "type":"A", "correlation_id": "2" }
{ "_id":"a-3", "type":"A", "correlation_id": "3" }
{ "_id":"b-1", "type":"B", "correlation_id": "1" }
```

How can I create a view that only show docs `id = a-2 and a-3`? I don't want to filter, just want to show all docs that haven't got `type B`. I could kinda do a `group by and count(*)` equivalent with view, but I can't do a `group by, having count(*) = 1` equivalent.

I'm using CouchDB 3.0.

Comment: I found some older posts.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413953/couchdb-equivalent-of-sql-not-in

But... the "list" function is no longer available.

"List functions are deprecated in CouchDB 3.0, and will be removed in CouchDB 4.0."

Perhaps I can't do "not in" using CouchDB and have to come up with a different document design.

Comment: are those docs the result of a view ? if they are just documents in the db your solution is a view.

Comment: Those "docs" with the "_id" properties above are CouchDB docs. I was able to do some "group by" using count and tiered keys for view, but I wasn't sure how to get "not in" behavior across 2 different types of docs.

Answer (score 0):

you could write a view :

```js
function (doc) {
  emit(doc.type, 1);
}
```

and then query the view using the key `"A"` and `include_docs=true` if you wanted the whole content of those documents.

If you not only want `"A"` but `"everything but B"` you can query from start to B and then from B to end and get all the documents that way.

Depending on your setup it might be easier to query the view with `group_level=1` so you get all the keys and then loop through them excluding B to get the rest of the info you're interested in.

Comment: Could you elaborate on " query from start to B and then from B to end and get all the documents that way"?

I want to get these docs.

{ "_id":"a-2", "type":"A", "correlation_id": "2" }
{ "_id":"a-3", "type":"A", "correlation_id": "3" }

Comment: Please elaborate on "query the view with group_level=1 so you get all the keys and then loop through them excluding B to get the rest of the info you're interested in".

I did try to use group_level=1 but maybe I didn't know what I was doing.

Comment: querying a view is really the basic block for couchdb. It's all described here https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/ddoc/views.html

Comment: If you want to use group_level=XX, your key needs to be an array to match the array you would be emitting in your view. So if you `emit([doc.type,doc._id],1)` you can then use group_level=1 when you query that view and this would return all the unique `doc.type`